# Formulating an SQL statement

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I need help formulating an SQL statement.The tables are

video(**video_id**, description, price, category_id)

category(**category_id**, description)

The query needs to produce a summary list showing the number of videos that belong to each category. Categories that do not have videoss assigned to them should also be included with a corresponding value of 0.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I think you need to use `LEFT JOIN`, `GROUP BY` and `COUNT()`...

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    c.id, c.description,
    coalesce(count(video_id), 0) total
from
    category c
    left join
    video v using(category_id)
group by 1, 2
order by 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Operation to Use :   `Join` and `Aggregate Function`

```
SELECT category.description, COUNT(*) AS TotalVideo FROM category LEFT JOIN video ON category.category_id = video.category_id GROUP BY category.description
```

Comment: Isn't this going to return (null) if there are no videos in that category? I managed to get zeros with the less elegant `SELECT cat_id, cat_name, CASE WHEN a.count IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE a.count END
FROM categories LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT vid_cat AS cat, count(*) as count
  FROM videos
  GROUP BY vid_cat
) AS a ON a.cat=cat_id`. I'm too tired to try and work the `CASE` statement into your solution - and also to restore the OP's column names. Sorry! :-)